# SharePoint Online Globalization and Localization

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, localization, designer-workflow

I am developing a SharePoint Online WebSite using SharePoint Designer 2010 that has several content types, lists and workflows.

One request is that the user must be able to select the language or culture from a DropDownBox and then the user interface must display and translate all elements in the selected culture.

How can I add translations for all the strings I use? Do I have to develop several versions of the same workflow, one for each language?

Any hits or suggestions?

B.

Comment: uh? no answer at all, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to do this. First there is the Office 365 language selection that is available in the cog, Office 365 settings. If your tenant is being synchronized with dirsync, then this option isn't available and is instead supplied via your on prem AD synchronizing the PreferredLanguage attribute. This translates the UI for you.

In SharePoint Online you have 2 options, enabling the multiuser interface by turning on the languages you want in the site settings, or by using variations. This is all explained here, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-multilingual-features-53411469-53e3-4570-95e2-3651f166174f.

With that out of the way, the only thing left to translate is your actual content. This would be done by exporting and importing the translations for things like your lists and custom site columns. You might even have to resort to javascript to do replacements for you.